# How to define a theme to correctly change text color globally?

Tags: android, styles, textview, themes

I am trying to change text color globally in my application, so by the instructions of http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html I defined two themes in a xml file and set it in the manifest file. But the result was: some text change and major don't, I tried a lot of things, did a lot of research but I wasn't successful in find a way to do this. I observed that the text that changed the color was normally in TextView's that were in first level of the layouts. I am not sure, but I think second level and, so, and the ones that were in listviews didn't change. Can anyone give me a clue? Thanks in advance.

my theme file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Dark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/green</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/yellow</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Manifest file entry:

```
<application
    android:name=".TestApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/test"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Dark">
```

Comment: Text color of TextViews or every text?

Comment: AFAIK each widget has its own parent style, and these are not chained together at all. So you would have to treat each widget separately.

Comment: answering: text color for all TextViews only.

Comment: correction: I made a mistake and now I saw tthat the only TextViews that are not changing are the ones in a ListView that was created by a SimpleAdapter.